# How to find this sum:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation

I am having problem in solving this equation. My approach is to treat each term as an summation of an infinite geometric progression and then we get an infinite geometric progression which give the right answer. But my teacher asked me to come up with a more technical solution, hope some one will help me.

$ \frac {x}{(1-x^2)}+\frac {x^2}{(1-x^4)}+\frac {x^4}{(1-x^8)}+\frac {x^8}{(1-x^{16})}+ \cdots \infty$
where $|x|<1.$

Comment: $$\dfrac1{1-x}-\dfrac1{1+x}=?$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee what do you mean?

Comment: He gave the appropriate hint to your problem. try it

Comment: @PrashantSingh re-write lab's fractions over a common denominator and see what you get.

Comment: Alright I am trying.

Comment: I seem to get $\frac {1}{1-x} $ using @lab bhattacharjee's method. Can't figure out the mistake.

Comment: $\dfrac1{1-x}-\dfrac1{1+x} = \dfrac{(1+x)-(1-x)}{(1-x)(1+x)}$

Answer (score 1):

$  f (x) = f(x^2) + x/(1-x^2) $ this is  in a functional equation form.
Now, take $ g =f - x/(1-x) $ and it turns out $ g (x) = g (x^2) =g (x^4)=......=0 $

So f= x/(1-x)

I hope it wil help

Answer (score 0):

First series will be an infinite sum of  odd powers of $x$; second one will be sum of powers of $x$ that are odd multiples of $2$ i.e., $x^2+x^6+x^{10}+\ldots$. In general the $k$-th series will sum of powers $x^m$ wheer $m=2^k\times \rm odd$. As every number can be uniquely written in this form (fundamental theorem of arithmetic), by rearranging the infinitely many infinite series we will get the final sum as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n =\frac x{1-x}$.

Comment: This was exactly what I had already said. I want a second method.